# Tag for the Food and Drug Administration (FDA)

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, Medical Sciences SE has tag [fda-food-drug-admin](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fda-food-drug-admin) for the U.S. [Food and Drug Administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_and_Drug_Administration) (FDA), without any synonyms. Since [food-and-drug-administration](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-and-drug-administration) is too long, I propose that the aforementioned tag be renamed [fda](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fda) or [us-fda](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-fda).

Comment: I don't see much purpose in having tags for particular regulatory agencies. Maybe a broad tag, with some particular agencies as synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer Bryan's suggestion, so [fda-food-drug-admin](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fda-food-drug-admin) has been renamed to [regulatory-agencies](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulatory-agencies) and [fda](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fda) has been made a synonym of [regulatory-agencies](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulatory-agencies).

As an aside, I must say I wish tags had history trails. I really wonder who made so many tags of the form [thing]-[synonym-for-thing]. Somebody really liked hyphens and really long, specific tags.